# Is the ehcache-web project is dead?

Tags: caching, ehcache

I am looking for the memory based java caching api esp., caching Web responses. I have ehcache & ehcache-web in my previous projects.It looks like the ehcache-web is not updated after OCT-2011. Is it not maintained any more? I don't want to use an inactive opensource project in production.

Comment: why is this question downvoted? Provide explanation

Comment: What are your requirements for the web tier caching? We may make them a part of Cacheonix.

Comment: @SlavaImeshev Thanks. I was looking for caching solution that caches entire the we response. Ehcache-web caches the entire response of a url. So after the first time the requests response is server from cache without going through the servlet/code.

Comment: You can look at Cacheonix web cache. It's a servlet filter that caches requests based on the url pattern and it's actively developed (latest version 2.2.2 released on May 12 2016. Hope this help.